# POST request fails to submit data object, returns "400 Bad Request"

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a `<button>` tag (no enclosing `<form>`) selected by jQuery to submit an Ajax POST request to an ajax-handler in Wordpress. An error object comes back indicating the back end isn't getting any data pairs. I did a manual browser get request with url params, just as a test, and the ajax handler worked. Here is my html and jQuery code:

```
  // html button. No form
      <button id="previousButton">Previous</button>

// ajax request function
function ajaxPost() {
  // 
  ?>
  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#previousButton').click(function() {
        var ajaxScript = { ajaxUrl : 'http://localhost/wptest2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' };

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: ajaxScript.ajaxUrl,
          contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            action: "selectTargetsWithOffset",
          },
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response, `=====success response=====`);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error, `=====error=====`);
          }
        });        
      });
    })
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'ajaxPost');
```

The error object:

```
options-general.php?page=fvc-settings:810 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (a)arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 1name: "abort"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:4[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]always: ƒ ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "always"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:2[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]complete: ƒ ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "add"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:2[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]done: ƒ ()error: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (a)readyState: 4responseJSON: 0responseText: "0"setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)state: ƒ ()status: 400statusCode: ƒ (a)statusText: "Bad Request"success: ƒ ()then: ƒ ()__proto__: Object "=====error====="
```

Any ideas why the k/v pairs aren't being sent to the back end? I see other apis in wordpress sending their own successful ajax requests but mine keep failing.

Comment: Try rewriting your error handler to something like `function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); }` - this may give you more info about _why_ error occurs.

Comment: Ok, I did this. It says "error" "bad request" for the 1st and 2nd log statements

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `jQuery.ajax()`, which leaves `data` field value format to yourself. As the `Content-Type` is defined as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, the value of `data` field should look like `foo=Hello&bar=World` (form data formatted key-value pair). `{action: "selectTargetsWithOffset"}` won't work.

The correct code would look like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ajaxScript.ajaxUrl,
  contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  dataType: "json",
  data: $.param({
    action: "selectTargetsWithOffset"
  }),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response, `=====success response=====`);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error, `=====error=====`);
  }
});
```

`$.param({action:"selectTargetsWithOffset"})` would convert JavaScript object to form data formatted string.